# Can't provide interfaces or types with MUI Styled Components

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Consider the following scenario:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

interface ParagraphProps {
  color: 'green' | 'blue';
}

const Paragraph = styled('p')<ParagraphProps>(({ color }) => ({
  color: color,
  fontSize: '18px',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
}));

Paragraph({ color: 'red' }); // No errors
```

The last line should complain because the color is not 'green' nor 'blue' but it doesn't, the props and values are not checked.

Expected:

```
Type '"red"' is not assignable to type '"green" | "blue"'.ts(2769)
```

If I change the import to

```
import { styled } from '@mui/styled-engine-sc';
```

-which VSCode suggested- it then works properly on ensuring that the props-values are what is declared, but whenever I run the project I get the following error:

```
ERROR export 'styled' (imported as 'styled') was not found in '@mui/styled-engine-sc'
```

Which is OK as I double checked and it effectively does not export any `styled` (don't know why the IDE suggested it and why it wasn't showing errors in dev time).

So If I use the mui/system `styled` function it won't work with TS interfaces or types.

The project is new just to test MUI, I've downloaded it with:

```bash
curl https://codeload.github.com/mui/material-ui/tar.gz/master | tar -xz --strip=2 material-ui-master/examples/material-cra-styled-components-ts
cd material-cra-styled-components-ts
```

I've tested with regular Styled-Components in the same project and everything works fine:

```
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

interface ParagraphProps {
  color: 'green' | 'blue';
}

const Paragraph = styled.p<ParagraphProps>`
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
  font-size: '18px';
  font-weight: 'bold';
`;

Paragraph({ color: 'blue' }); // OK
Paragraph({ color: 'red' }); // Type '"red"' is not assignable to type '"green" | "blue"'.ts(2769)
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Opened a GitHub issue to track progress: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/37214